# Start multiple Animated.timing at once with React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to start multiple React Native animations at once, with one callback for all animations. The example works fine, but I don't like the fact, that I have to start one after the other and having only one animation with a callback. Is there a more elegant way?

```js
Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {
    toValue: 0,
    duration: 300
}).start();

Animated.timing(this.state.height, {
    toValue: 0,
    duration: 300
}).start(() => {
    // callback
});
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can use [Animated.parallel](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html#composing-animations)!

```js
Animated.parallel([
    Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 300
    }),
    Animated.timing(this.state.height, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 300
    })
]).start(() => {
    // callback
});
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was searching for! Thank you

Comment: It's strange that callback doesn't work for me. It works only inside parallel.