# Apply different animations on different items in a screen of React native app

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, animation

I've tried to apply animations on 2 items in a screen. There are two images and I want to apply animations on both of them simultaneously but different animations. One should slide from left and other from right together.

I've searched for different sources but found nothing. There are examples to apply multiple animations together but those will be applied to all the items in `<Animated.View>`

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.animatedMargin = new Animated.Value(0);

        // I want to fire both animations from here
        setTimeout(() => {
            // this._slideAnimation('left');
            // this._slideAnimation('right');
            // I actually want to know how to achieve this
        }, 100);
    }

    _slideAnimation(direction) {
        if (direction === 'left'){
            Animated.timing(this.animatedMargin, {
                toValue: width,
                duration: 1000
            }).start();
        } else {
            Animated.timing(this.animatedMargin, {
                toValue: 0,
                duration: 1000
            }).start();
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ styles.container }}>
                {/* I want to slide this from left to right */}
                <Animated.View style={[ styles.ainmated, { left: this.animatedMargin } ]}>
                    <Image source={ left_image } />
                </Animated.View>

                {/* and this one in reverse direction */}
                <Animated.View style={[ styles.ainmated, { right: this.animatedMargin } ]}>
                    <Image source={ right_image } />
                </Animated.View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

But in this way, only one animation can be applied at once. I've evern tried [Animated.parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40901099/7109362) so that multiple animations can be applied in parallel but **Both `<Animated.View>` tag will be animated with same animation rather than separate ones**

So, how can I achieve **different animations** on **different objects/components** in a single screen **simultaneously** in React native?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need two animations to achieve this.

Here is a full working example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text,Animated,View, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('screen')

const ITEM_SIZE = 60

export default class App extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
      this.animatedMargin = new Animated.Value(0);
      setTimeout(() => {
          this._slideAnimation();
      }, 1000);
    }

    _slideAnimation() {
      Animated.timing(this.animatedMargin, {
        toValue: (width / 2) - ITEM_SIZE,
        duration: 1000
      }).start()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={ styles.container }>
                <Animated.View style={[ styles.animated, { left: this.animatedMargin } ]}>
                    <View style={[styles.imagePlaceholder, { backgroundColor: '#0070ff'}]} />
                </Animated.View>

                <Animated.View style={[ styles.animated, { right: this.animatedMargin } ]}>
                   <View style={[ styles.imagePlaceholder, {backgroundColor: '#008080'} ]} />
                </Animated.View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  animated: {
    position: 'absolute'
  },
  imagePlaceholder: {
    width: ITEM_SIZE,
    height: ITEM_SIZE
  }
});
```

Comment: Just one more thing; Currently, both animations are starting from middle & ending in sides. I want them in reverse direction i.e. Start from either side and meet in the mid.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work after I tested it completely. I only runs the first animation in `setTimeout()` not working on the other one... I am doing some edits in the answer to mention the issues. Kindly have a look at it!

Comment: Please have a look at my latest edit, it should accomplish what you were trying to achieve. I've replaced the `<Image>` just to showcase how the animation could work with generic views.

Comment: Thanks dude... this is what I asked for and now its proper as one animation is used...